# Samba: query_name_response: Multiple (2) responses received

Tags: samba

I have two Samba servers in a network with two Linux and a lot of Windows hosts.

Both Linux hosts run a Samba server, with the same (very basic) configuration:

```
[global]
workgroup = PRAXIS
security = user
map to guest = Bad Password
hosts allow = 192.168.10.0/24
hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0
log file = /var/log/samba/samba.log
max log size = 10000
log level = 1
```

Both host a QEMU virtual machine and use a network bridge.

Everything works, however, one one of the two machines, I get log entries like this:

```
Feb 27 09:52:54 anmeldung2 nmbd[2991]: [2024/02/27 09:52:54.535310,  0] ../../source3/nmbd/nmbd_namequery.c:109(query_name_response)
Feb 27 09:52:54 anmeldung2 nmbd[2991]:   query_name_response: Multiple (2) responses received for a query on subnet 192.168.10.10 for name PRAXIS<1d>.
Feb 27 09:52:54 anmeldung2 nmbd[2991]:   This response was from IP 192.168.10.98, reporting an IP address of 192.168.10.98.
```

The only difference is that this machine has an additional WLAN device. However, restricting the interface with

```
interfaces = br0 lo
bind interfaces only = yes
```

also didn't help, I still get those messages.

I have no idea how to avoid this. I found [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/827985/samba-nmbd-query-name-response-multiple-2-responses-received) describing this exact problem, but none of the solutions mentioned there help.

What is causing this? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Disable netbios. DNS is a thing and works. https://serverfault.com/questions/155753/how-can-i-disable-samba-broadcasting-features

Comment: Preventing nmbd from starting seems to help! Thanks for the hint, I have to investigate this …